# I have an endpoint of /oauth/login. I don't know which class it is in , how can I debug to find it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an endpoint of `/oauth/login`, a public endpoint. And I don't know which class it is in. As I know, there is an `TokenEndpoint` with '/oauth/token', but not with `/oauth/login`.

I try to make a breakpoint in `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#doPost` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#doGet`, but it doesn't step into.

So how can I debug to find it out ?

Comment: All right, I have found it in `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer`

Comment: For folks that stumble on this same question, you might share what you did to debug/find it.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` - a base Filter used for authentication. This also gives a good idea of the high level flow of authentication and how pieces work together. [Spring Security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/authentication/architecture.html)

Spring Security provides support for username and password being provided through an html form. This section provides details on how form based authentication works within Spring Security. [Form Login reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html)

`loginProcessingUrl` default is `/login`, and also can see `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer#FormLoginConfigurer`